# Can i take package of cpython?

Tags: python, c, dll, installation

I used cpython api to load py from C/C++.

But, if i want not setup cpython in client, can I take package dll of cpython in my program?

How to do that?

Comment: Can you redistribute the Python interpreter? In general, yes, so long as you respect the license as shown by `python -c 'license()'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installer-builders like [PyInstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org) (cross-platform) and [py2exe](http://www.py2exe.org/) (Windows only) basically do that job for you in a general way, except that the executable at the heart of the produced package is their own instead of yours.

But basically, you can imitate their behavior in terms of setting up a `.zip` file with all the Python library modules you need (or just zip up everything in the standard python library if you want to allow python code running form your app to import anything from there), and follow the simple advice in the [Embedding Python in Another Application](http://docs.python.org/extending/embedding.html) section of the Python docs.

Note that embedding Python equals extending Python plus a little bit of code to initialize and finalize the interpreter itself and a little bit of packaging as I just mentioned; if you've never writted Python extensions I would suggest practicing that first since it's the most substantial part of the task (not all that hard with helpers such as [boost python](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/python/doc/index.html), but more work if you choose to do it as the "bare C" level instead).

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to setup Python to embed it in applications. The core of the Python interpreter is available as a shared library which you can dynamically load in your application and distribute with it.

Read on [embedding Python](http://docs.python.org/extending/embedding.html) in the official docs. Also, [this article](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/8497?page=0,0) seems nice and comprehensive for Linux. For Windows, [read the notes here](http://effbot.org/pyfaq/how-can-i-embed-python-into-a-windows-application.htm).

Here's [another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1387906/c-with-python-embedding-crash-if-python-not-installed) that discusses this issue.

Answer (score 0):

The Python license is probably hard to understand for a non-lawyer, non-native English speaker. So yes, you can redistribute the unmodified DLL as it contains the copyright notice within it.

It would be polite to give credit like "This program contains the Python Language Interpreter version X.XX http://python.org for more information" or similar somewhere in the program or documentation.