# Deployment of Python to support embedded and extended ways

Tags: c++, python, deployment, swig, scripting-language

I'm currently trying to deploy a site-package using Python 2.7 in a project written in C++ and using SWIG. Everything works very well. Our application is distributed to many clients, and we have one big existential question: should our installation package install Python itself (let's say in 'C:\Python27'), or should we include only the python27.dll along with the DLLs and Lib folder of Python, as explained here: [C++ with Python embedding: crash if Python not installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1387906/c-with-python-embedding-crash-if-python-not-installed)

For the embedded way of using our site-package, I see no problem of not installing Python using its install program (from python.org). But for the extended usage, if we take the approach of NOT installing Python on the client machine, I am wondering what will happen if the client installs another thid-party library (like numpy). Will numpy work even though Python 2.7 has not been installed properly (no registry keys have been set, etc.) And if the client wants to use IDLE or PyDev, how can he do that if Python has not been previously installed on its machine?

Comment: Just to be clear, your application allows clients to write their own extensions using python? And you want them to be able to use third party python modules in those extensions?

Comment: We created our own site-package, allowing clients to interact with our software using Python. It allows client to run their own scripts in our software, in an embedded way, using our library (site-package). It also allows clients to run their scripts outside our software, using PyDev for example. We do not want to add any limitation to what the clients can do. If they want to add their own extensions or use any third-party library, we want to support that as well.

Comment: Well, if someone wants to run scripts outside the software they're going to have to have python installed anyways right?

Comment: That was the point I wanted to confirm... so there is no way the user can run scripts outside our software if Python is not installed? User cannot use the Python executable or anything else?

Comment: I'm no python expert, but I wouldn't think so.