# Trouble with modules while embedding python in C++

Tags: python, c++, dll, embed, python-c-api

I'm making a .dll for an .exe program and embedding python in it. It worked fine with this simple .py program

```
from time import *
##import OptimRestriction

def test_callsign(b):
    ...(simple script)
    return
```

What I did was copy the .py program, the Dll and Lib folders into the xxx.exe folder, like is said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1387906/c-with-python-embedding-crash-if-python-not-installed).

But as soon as I uncomment the import of `OptimRestriction` the debug crashes.  First it starts loading symbols when the call to the thread that initializes and deals with Python is called: `_ctypes.pyd`,`_sockets.pyd`,`sst_pyd`,`harshlib.pyd`,`unicodedata.pyd`,`tkinter.pyd`, all modules that the `OptimRestriction` does not use.

The error given after the debug crashes is:

`Unhandled exception at 0x1E0AA0C5 (python27.dll) in xxx.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000004.`

And it breaks on the `_callthreadstart` function.

`OptimRestriction` is a long program that imports a lot of modules (that are also in the .exe folder). Here's the list of its imports:

```
from GrafFunc import *
from LogFunc import *
from DinamicaFunc import *
from Dinamica2 import *
from CDR import *
...
import sys
import cProfile"
```

What it seems to me is that the thread takes too long to start because the debug starts loading those files for a long time, and so it gives an error. Am I correct? And if so, why is it loading those files if `OptimRestriction`and its impots don't use them?

Edit:New information. It crashes saying `Can't import module` on this line: 
`pModule = PyImport_Import(pName);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After long hours of reducing the problem to some lines of code, i just found out that the problem was in the lines where some of the modules opened .txt files to read.

I thought that having the .txt files in the same folder of the .py programs was the correct thing to do, but it seems that I needed to copy them to the folder of my c++ plugin (I think that's because while I'm debugging, the system path is changed for my plug-in folder since the writing and reading of pyhton is done to/from there)

Problem solved!