# How to clean Lib and Dll folder

Tags: python, c++, dll, embed

I'm making a .dll for an .exe program and embedding python in it. For it to work I need to include the .py programs and the Dll and Lib folders in the .exe folder like it says in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1387906/c-with-python-embedding-crash-if-python-not-installed). It works fine on my computer but i want to use the .dll in other computers.

So what I want is to erase everything that isn't necessary from the Lib and Dlls folders (right now the two folders have 210Mb)

I already looked into `ModuleFinder`(like it says [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/modulefinder.html)) and managed to erase some modules. But that's not what I want. `ModuleFinder` tells me the unused modules but how do I clean them and all the other unneeded files from Lib and Dll when there are thousands of files there?

Anyone knows any good way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

"Dependency Walker" is a tool which can show you which DLLs are needed. That includes both a static mode (which are needed just to load the EXE?) and a dynamic mode (which are needed at runtime?)